Unable to modify SPO List column's width and remove white space
I have a SharePoint online list, and I am unable to modify the column width, by making it smaller and remove all extra unneeded "white-space".
This is the Json code I tried, the color parts works, but the column width does not.
{
  "$schema": https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json,
  "elmType": "div",
  "txtContent": "@currentField",
  "style": {
    "color": "green",
    "width": "50px"
  }
}

Here's a screenshot of the current list, the red arrow is the part I want to reduce/minimize so I can fit more columns to the user's screen.

Any help will be appreciated.
Shai
